# Reference for bound $x_{0} \le n^{2}$ in solutions to the Diophantine equation $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2} = x_{0}\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Using Vieta jumping, [one can prove that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4490316/710460), if $x_{0}, x_{1}, \dotsc,
x_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ are such that
\begin{equation*}
   \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2} =
   x_{0}\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i},
\end{equation*}
then $x_{0} \le n^{2}$.

I need this bound as a lemma for something else.  But this bound
seems like something that would already be known.  Is there a good
reference in the literature?